Are there any modern image formats that use plain Huffman coding?
I have some images that are very noisy, but the values are all in a narrow range of near-zero uint8 values. I think Huffman coding might be optimal for compressing them, since there is a lot of bit-wise redundancy but not a lot of sequence redundancy. However I can't find any image formats that use the plain bit-wise algorithm without encoding sequences (like PNG or Deflate do). The closest I found was an obsolete Unix command line tool called "pack". Is there an image format that uses plain old Huffman compression?
Bonus points if there's a Python encoder for it.


This looks related https://narainsreehith.medium.com/huffman-coding-on-image-d6092bed5821

I believe LZW coding not only optimizes sequences but also limited character sets, just like Huffman.  You could try it and see if it gets the compression ratio you expect.

@MarkRansom LZW compression performed very poorly, file size was 2.9 Gb. Pure huffman (from Mark Adler's reply) was 2.3 Gb. So far the best lossless compression I've found is PNG at 2.1 Gb.

Yes, the PNG image format. You can request that zlib use the Z_HUFFMAN_ONLY strategy for a PNG image. You can also try Z_FILTERED which is not Huffman-only, but is tuned for the filtered image data in PNG files, and does less string matching. Try those along with Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY on your images, to see how they compare. All of them will take advantage of the small range of your pixel values with Huffman coding.

This worked! I had to use:
zlib.compressobj(strategy=zlib.Z_HUFFMAN_ONLY).compress(Image.tobytes())
since Pillow doesn't allow the Z_HUFFMAN_ONLY strategy for Image.save(..., format="png"). As it turned out the compression was slightly worse than full png compression. Oh well. Thanks for the help!

@markemus Have you tried Z_FILTERED? I'd be curious to know where that falls.

I tested it, both options came out to approximately the same size.
